# splash screen in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, landscape

I am developing an application which is in LandScape mode Only. In my application ,I am using a splash Screen Image (480 X 320). When I am running Xcode then Splash image appears in Portrait mode only but the view is in LandScape mode only.

Can Anyone suggest how to implement splah Screen in LandScape mode.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please edit your Info.plist file to add the UIInterfaceOrientation key with the appropriate value (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft), as shown in ListABC. This provides a hint to the system to set the orientation of the status bar appropriately at launch time.

ListABC: Starting your application in landscape mode

UIInterfaceOrientation
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

this link will help you

http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdkdevelopment/browse_thread/thread/ef734379136f09e9?pli=1